# PreparedStatement is not matching a record on calling execute()

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert a record in the database if it does not exist already. The record exists if the 'description' field matches with the same field of record to be inserted.

In the code, executing the PreparedStatement has no effect on the variable 'created'. The method 'createIdea()' should return true if new record has been inserted otherwise return false (i.e. record already exists).

```
public static boolean createIdea(User userIns,String description,int categoryId) throws  ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM idea WHERE description = ?");
    ps.setString(1, description);
    boolean found = ps.execute();   // If description exists
    ps.close();
    if(found) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO idea (description, user_id, status, posted_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, description);
        ps.setInt(2, userIns.getId());
        ps.setString(3, "Pending");
        ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
        int n = ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        if(n != 0) {
            // Other PreparedStatements
        }
    }
    con.close();
    return true;
}
```

Table Description:

```
mysql> desc idea;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status      | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| posted_date | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The method createIdea() always returns flase. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is the boolean value returned by execute()? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--

Comment: The execute method returns a boolean to indicate the form of the first result. You must call either the method getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result; you must call getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

Returns:
true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result

Comment: Did you try running the query on the sql console itself and see what is the result. Since description is a text value even a single space can change the result from the prepared statement.

Comment: createIdea() always returns false even after passing a new description...
Value of found is true for description that does not exist in db..

Comment: @umer_farooque you didn't answer my question. Read the javadoc I linked to, carefully, and ask yourself when the execute() method returns true and when it returns false. It's right there, in the documentation. Then ask yourself why you use execute() although you know that what you have is a select query, and thus that executQuery() would be much simpler and more appropriate.

Comment: You should be using `executeQuery()`, not `execute()`. Makes life a lot simpler.

Comment: @JBNizet ps.execute() is returning true every time..i.e. even for a new value of description which is not in db.

Comment: Yes, and that is completely normal and expected **if you read the documentation**. Have you finally read it? What does it say? When does execute() return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PreparedStatement#execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) from javadoc states:

> Returns: `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

It will always return `true` on a `SELECT` query.

As Mark Rotteveel pointed out, it will also return `true`
 even on an **empty** `ResultSet` (which is still a `ResultSet`). On the contrary, it will return `false` if there is **no** `ResultSet` or there **is**/**is not** an update count.

It would be better to use `executeQuery()` which will return a `ResultSet` ([`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())).

```
ResultSet found = ps.executeQuery();    
if (!found.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: With that description, it is important to keep in mind that an empty result set is still a result. The _"there is no result"_ in that documentation means that the query produced neither a - possibly empty - result set nor an update count.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for pointing out that information. WIll update accordingly.

Comment: Yeah...
Got it working now by using executeQuery()
The condition looks like this..

if(found.next()) return false;

Comment: @umer_farooque While your approach might be correct, `next()` will move the cursor to check for other rows in `ResultSet`. Instead, you can just call `isBeforeFirst()` to test if there is any row returned without moving the cursor (check if empty or not).

Answer (score 0):

As Prince Vegeta quoted the doc and said `execute()` for `select` query will return true, you can try like shown there or just simply try to check if your resultset has any value returned:

```
ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();    
if (rs.next()) {    
    return true;
}
```